# C function to Python

Tags: python, c

Can someone help to make Python version of function.
Thanks

```
unsigned char asap_xor(unsigned char *msg, int len) {
    unsigned char xor_val = 0;
    int i;
    xor_val = msg[0];
    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        xor_val ^= msg[i];
    }
    xor_val = 13 ^ xor_val;
    xor_val = xor_val | 0x40;
    return (xor_val);
}
```

my python version but error

```
def asap_xor(msg, len):
    xor_val = msg[0]
    for i in range(1, len):
        xor_val ^= msg[i]
    xor_val = byte(13 ^ xor_val)
    xor_val = byte(xor_val | 0x40)
    return (xor_val)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^=: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of what you are trying to do in the function and also expected output and sample input

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74029861/edit) to include your attempt so far.

Comment: Assuming `msg` is a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) object you can use `13 ^ reduce(xor, msg) | 0x40`. Imports: [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), [`xor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor). [*Example*](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETv@YqlpwQ8tKaC@DFKbBMtmOyy2UAF/z2mos5tmDePnnLHZI/EtQbGCKGkSRAfGZZIyALs5zJ59RmRPDtB/m0rslKzD@Cyo0trOuabOSloYS@FEwwWzl@HbsAONgJe0K9jrxTxkkT/39du2Nvx0BmzGWp9Aw).

Comment: Not just `bytes` object, any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) values will fit. [*Example*](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwFET3OcWnqwSyaJpWxKsYldimtWDzw28KFbx7jKIudHbDezPhFi/o9TZQSj3hBP3i24h4nWGcAlIEct3SOvaCGBzZiPRhKxJjnevBzjaccuPTPIgdgxxycSEPSsPx/cGzIOFpwB3KtS4ZCzT6yL/rc2GUqYw2tWkKIX7xXkmoJGgJtYTm8C@Q9YPj2doIIVJ6AA).

Comment: @bit, length of your message is `125`, you pass `124` which exclude last symbol, that's why results are different. If that's expected behavior, you can implement it using simple slice notation ( `reduce(xor, msg[:length])` ) or with [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) ( `reduce(xor, islice(msg, length))` ). [*Updated function*](https://tio.run/##VY3BCoMwEETvfsUcDXiw2EMp9FdaRDcaiNmwWUGh/56G1kK7p4E3bzbuOnPoLlFytsIL7BoGZfYJboksCqFxHah6Q44kvbJ82cbyAU5J/iyXvCtWNZJFn/r4KNV6SVMDT2HS@daaa4VyQrpKwKnD/XhVl2pzDPwqBs4eEeQToTCDJ9rt3Ob8Ag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your task is to "translate" code from C to Python line by line [@th33lf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214247/th33lf)'s answer is perfectly fine.

However, you can use built-in features of Python which allows you to implement same logic in one-liner *(suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74029861/10824407#comment130712056_74029861) comment)*:

```py
13 ^ reduce(xor, msg) | 0x40
```

[`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) iterates over iterable and applies provided function *(we used [`xor()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor))* to every item using result of previous step as first argument.

So *pythonic* version of your C function is:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def asap_xor(msg):
    return 13 ^ reduce(xor, msg) | 0x40
```

Note that `msg` should be an iterable of `int` values *(already said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74029861/10824407#comment130712241_74029861) comment)*. If your input value is string you can use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to convert [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) to [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).

If you need to keep `len` argument *(as you've said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74029861/10824407#comment130712819_74029861) comment)* you can pass sliced `msg` to `reduce()` *(check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74029861/10824407#comment130712994_74029861) comment)*. I'd set default length argument value to `0` and use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) only if some non-zero length passed to function.

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor
from itertools import islice

def asap_xor(msg, length=0):
    return 13 ^ reduce(xor, islice(msg, length) if length else msg) | 0x40
```

Usage:

```py
asap_xor("message".encode())                     # 102
asap_xor("message".encode(), 6)                  # 67
asap_xor(b"message")                             # 102
asap_xor(b"message", 6)                          # 67
asap_xor([109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101])     # 102
asap_xor([109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101], 6)  # 67
```

---

Comment: whilst I totally sympathise with the link, answers are totally not the place to include links to material entirely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @user438383, that's why I asked one of moderators in Python chat is it okay to add one-line footer.

Comment: Loved this answer, indeed is the more 'pythonic' solution!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what version of python you are on, but for python 3.5+ or so, this should work:

```
def asap_xor(msg):        
    xor_val = msg[0]
    for m in msg[1:]:
        xor_val ^= m
    xor_val = (13 ^ xor_val)
    xor_val = (xor_val | 0x40)

    return xor_val

print(asap_xor("test".encode('utf8')))
print(asap_xor(b"test"))
```

Comment: @bit I assumed you would be passing a string, not byte array. Updated the answer.

Comment: msg = msg.encode('utf8')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'